# Excel interpreting certain decimal numbers as dates in CSV created by Python script

Tags: python, excel, csv

Where I live, the comma is typically used as the decimal separator, and the period is the standard way to write dates.

When I write decimal numbers that can be interpreted as dates to a CSV file, they automatically show up as dates when the file is opened in Excel, as it assumes that's what I want based on the standard settings for representing dates. For example, the following code:

```
import csv

with open("testfile.csv", 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    csv_writer.writerow([1.2, 2.502, 3.63, 4.001, 5.667, 6.23])
```

appears like this in Excel:
[image: Result in Excel]

Is there a way to get the values to show up properly for all users who run the program without telling them to change their settings?

I have tried disabling quoting in the csv.writer constructor and converting the floats to strings before writing, but that did not solve it. A possible solution that worked was to convert to string and add a space character at the start, but I'd prefer to avoid that to make reading/copying values from the file less of a hassle. I'd also prefer not changing the decimal separator to a comma.

Comment: This is an excel issue, not a python issue.

Comment: @roganjosh The question was how I can make sure any user sees the right format WITHOUT changing their Excel settings, so I'd say it's more a Python question than an Excel question.

Comment: I assume csv is associated with Excel. don't open csv file by click on it. Use Data tab ->Open -> from text Set the column type in the wizard when asked

Comment: @Moris You CANNOT because Excel decides to read a CSV as it chooses. I understood your question.

Comment: @roganjosh Then why not say that in the first comment, if it answers the question?

Comment: CSV files are not specific to Python. They can be created by any number of tools. In fact, one could use any basic text editor and manually create or edit a CSV file. There is no way to format a CSV file which will force Excel to interpret a value as a certain format. You must use Excel's options and/or settings to force it to recognize a specific type of value.

Comment: I know nothing about you. I could either over-pitch it or under-pitch the response. The only time I can get a grip on your understanding is when you decide to use CAPS in response to me. My response was correct in either case.

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry about the caps, I just meant to emphasize the word (I wanted to italize it, but didn't see that it was an option), not to appear aggressive or anything. My problem with your first response was that you chose to just say that the question didn't belong here, and not answer it when you knew the answer. You could have done both.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it didn't belong here; it's an Excel issue. I can change the tags for you but I don't think it'll do you favours. It's just an Excel issue (which in no way has any monopoly on the CSV format). I don't think there's anything you can do when _writing_ the data to make it "right". It is not a format that takes metadata like `parquet` but I have no idea off the top of my head whether it can preserve this kind of formatting change

Comment: The genetics scientists recently changed the names of a number of genes because Excel kept destroying them when they were included in CSV files.  That was the only robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the simplest solution is to make sure numbers don't match date styles by ensuring 3 decimal spaces:

```
import csv

with open("testfile.csv", 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    csv_writer.writerow([f"{x:.3f}" for x in [1.2, 2.502, 3.63, 4.001, 5.667, 6.23]])
```

If you don't need the file to be a CSV, there may be other solutions working with the xlsx file format directly via a package such as XlsxWriter.